# What are the key considerations I should have when choosing between Phaser 2 and 3?

Tags: phaser

I'm planning on experimenting with basic HTML5 game development. Since I'm just learning the ropes I'm sure either engine could support my needs. At the same time I would prefer to focus on the engine/platform that will serve as the best possible foundation when I am ready to produce games. I don't expect to make millions on the games but it seems like a fun hobby that has the potential to bring in a little bit of money.

With that in mind are there any considerations or trade-offs I should be aware of between Phaser 2 and Phaser 3? Is it as simple as the bigger the version number the more awesome sauce included, so Phaser 3 is the natural choice? Based on the research I've done it seems like Phaser 2 will still undergo improvements/bug fixes as a community supported product so it isn't like Phaser 2 is abandoned in favor of Phaser 3. I also saw that the rendering engine was changed between Phaser 2 and Phaser 3. Should this be a major consideration even though I don't have the art skills nor budget to hire an artist so I can create flashy games? Or alternatively is deciding between these two engines so meaningless that I may as well just flip a coin?